For early Android phones lacking NFC does the ACR122U 13.56MHz Contactless Smart Card Reader-Writer add usable NFC?
The trigger problem, here, is finding a way to download a Ticketmaster NFC-based ticket with their Android app, store it in the Android Wallet, then use the ETEKJOY ACR122U to display the ticket for entry to a concert. The ACR122U is shown writing to the RFID poker chips. Same or different ? Practical explanation will be much appreciated !!

The physical capability to communicate via NFC is not the only thing what is required. The other part is the software. The necessary APIs are defined since Android API10 (Android 2.3.3) however I am not sure if the API is available on devices that do not have a built-in NFC reader and if they have if it is possible to make the the Android NFC API uses the external NFC reader.

The Software as suggested = take a trip to the GOOGLE PLAY store = Query < acr122 usb nfc reader utils > which is a built-in at the store. As soon as acr122u was typed it popped up. I'm looking at 7 apps on the screen !! Gotta love it. I'll post inquiries about the software options in separate / new questions. Btw: thank you!
